# Fetching data from a table in the alphabetical order of the first name in android

Tags: android

I got an sqlite exception while executing the query given below.

```
Cursor c=db.query("patient_tbl", new String[] {" first_name"},
         null, null, null, null,"DESC");
```

Exception is :

```
08-19 16:55:35.748: E/AndroidRuntime(2808):android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
no such column: DESC: , while compiling: SELECT  first_name FROM patient_tbl 
ORDER BY DESC
```

Comment: I changed to this Cursor c=db.query("patient_tbl",null, null, null, null, null,"first_name"); Now works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last argument in `db.query` is `orderBy` which says how to order the rows, formatted as an SQL ORDER BY clause (excluding the ORDER BY itself).  Hence you have to mention the column name also..

You just mentioned `DESC` only  so you will get `no such column` `SQLiteException`

So Use

```
Cursor c=db.query("patient_tbl", null,
         null, null, null, null,"first_name ");
```

Comment: By using above code i got 08-19 17:16:36.148: E/AndroidRuntime(3744): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.